# What is the output value/type of this query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I've been trying to get the score of a post, which is stored in a MySQL database. I've been able to do this using the following code:

```
$query_getpostscore = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT score FROM theshitp_posts.mainfeed WHERE id ='$postid'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_getpostscore, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$score = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$row['score']);
```

However, I was wondering why simply writing the following does not work:

```
$query_getpostscore = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT score FROM theshitp_posts.mainfeed WHERE id ='$postid'");
```

Surely this should give the numeric value of the score stored in the database, where `id=$id`?

Why does the first example work, but not the second?

Comment: Escaping is meant mainly to prevent SQL injection.. why are you escaping things you already pulled from the db.. remove the last line you don't need it.

Comment: well don't remove it just remove the escape.. `$score = $row['score'];`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the output of mysqli\_query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58987530/what-is-the-output-of-mysqli-query)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though you might be getting a single column in a single row, `mysqli_query` is going to return a resultset to you (a `mysqli_result` object). You might "know" that this is only going to be one value, but there is no way for the computer to know that this will always be the case.