# What is the output of mysqli_query?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So im writing notes in my studies and im explaining what is "going on" in each line of code when connecting, fetching and closing a database.

> $conn = mysqli_connect();

- connects to host and target a table.

> $varr = "SELECT * FROM table;";

- just a string.

> $varr2 = mysqli_query($conn, $varr);

- ??

If i use

> var_dump($varr2)

my output is:

> object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0)
>   ["field_count"]=> int(5) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1)
>   ["type"]=> int(0) }

What does this data mean?

by definition, mysqli_query performs a query on the database, and the definition of query is to ask a question. 
I dont see any connection between the output of

> var_dump(mysqli_query)

and its definition.

Comment: What kind of study? And what else do you expect?

Comment: You attributed the result f your query to the variable `$varr2`. The result of a query is an object that represents the returned data from the query. If you'd like to more easily understand it and manipulate it, use `mysqli_fetch_assoc($varr2)` and you'll have your data in an associative array. But it sounds to me like you need to do a lot of reading and googling first.

Comment: I want to understand how codes work rather than just accepting that "this is how you do it"  
it looks like ["field_count"] is the number of columns in the table and ["num_rows"] is the number of rows in the table, ["current_field"], ["length"] and ["type"] i dont understand. 

Paulo Hgo "you attributed the result" 
If I understand this right, the output is the attributes of the table?

Comment: What does the result do and what does it output are different things. Which one you are asking about?

Comment: Mysqli_connect doesn't target the table and mysqli_query doesn't output anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it's a fair question. That's a very good intention to understand how things work too.

However, what does a thing do and what does it output are two different things. mysqli_query is not intended to output anything. So you just bit a bit too deep and went astray.

The answer to the question "what does mysqli query do" is fairly simple: it runs your query against a database.

What does it return is a different thing. For `SELECT` queries it returns [an object of mysqli_result class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php). Hence such output.

This object is needed to make use of the selected data. You can use this object's methods and properties to get the information about the returned data.

- There are several properties though you'll never need them. Properties, however, describe the returned resultset, not the whole table. If you select only one column, the field count will be 1, not 5. This number is rather useless though as you can always count the number of fields in the fetched row. The same goes for the number of rows.
- of methods you'd likely use only three - fetch_assoc() or fetch_all() most of time, depends on the number of rows expected, and fetch_row() occasionally when fetch_assoc() is not convenient.

#### An important note.

You actually seldom use mysqli_query(), because most of time we run SQL queries using PHP variables. And once even a single variable is going to be used in the query, another set of functions must be used instead of mysql_query(). Here is my article that explains the process, [Mysqli SELECT query with prepared statements](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli_examples/prepared_select)

Hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 2):

## What it does

The purpose of `mysqli_query()` is to execute a static SQL query **without any variable data**. As soon as you want to use  any variable input you should use prepared statements.

It will immediately send the query to the MySQL server and wait for response. Once MySQL is finished executing the query, mysqli_query will fetch all the information back to PHP internally.

## What it returns

The return value could be a boolean(true/false) for example when MySQL returns no results when INSERT or UPDATE query is performed. If you use it to execute SELECT it will return an instance of [`mysqli_result`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) class. This object is what enables you to fetch the DB records.

`mysqli_result` contains useful methods for fetching the data in different formats. For example:

- `fetch_assoc()`/`fetch_row()`/`fetch_array()` will give you a single row as an array
- `fetch_object()` returns a single row as an object
- `fetch_all()` returns all the rows as a multi-dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, $varr2 in your example becomes a pointer to the result set. As someone said, you can fetch it all to an array, but on a big result that is a memory hog. If you use it as a pointer, the DB keeps it ready so you don't have to worry about memory issues.

Comment: Unfortunately, the resultset is already on the PHP side, and a memory hog even before you fetch

Comment: Not from my experience. If you never pull the query data into an array, it's always waiting as an incoming stream of data, and you can pull it in row by row. I work with tons of data sometimes and can say for sure that the DB Server keeps the result set ready for you without taking up the memory space of PHP unless you pull it out in row, array, etc...

Comment: Oh I am not talking about someone's experience. I am just explaining how it actually works

Comment: If you work with tons of data you may want to tell mysqli to run an unbuffered query to save your memory

Comment: See here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php  What you want is the result mode setting: USE result or STORE result

Comment: Yes, exactly. Which makes your answer a bit misleading and not strictly on topic